# What is the binary operations in $\mathbb{D}(n)$

Tags: group-theory

I am using Joseph A gGallian for group theory.I came across something named Dihedral group $\mathbb{D}(n)$. The author uses only Caley table and does not describe the binary operation of this group algebrically.I searched on internet and came across different defnitions of binary operations and this confused me a bit.

So I request that someone please tell me the binary operations.

Comment: Are you happy with group presentations? $D_n$ is generated by elements $a$ and $b$, subject to the conditions $a^n=1$, $b^2=1$, and $ba=a^{-1}b$.

Comment: A Cayley table *does* define the binary operation algebraic---it's just not always as illuminating as other characterizations.

Comment: You can think of the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ (or sometimes $D_n$) as the group of symmetries of the regular $n$-gon, and so viewed it consists of suitable reflections and rotations.

Comment: You can derive the relations given in @GerryMyerson 's comment from the definition of $a$ as the "smallest" rotation of the regular $n$-gon (that preserves symmetry) and $b$ as a reflection. Imagine a regular $n$-gon with vertices labeled $0, 1, \ldots, n-1$ in the obvious order. Then $a$ maps each vertex $k$ to $k + 1$ (addition modulo $n$), and $b$ fixes $0$; interchanges $1$ and $n - 1$; $2$ and $n - 2$, and so on (figure out where that "so on" ends, depending on the parity of $n$).

Comment: You can also consider the $n$ vertices as the $n$ roots of unity in the complex plane. Then $a$ maps each $e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}$ to $e^{i\frac{2(k+1)\pi}{n}}$, and $b$ maps each root to its conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

One particular algebraic representation for $D_n$ is the following: picture a regular $n$-gon in the plane. Then $D_n$ is the set of symmetries of the $n$-gon.

In particular, let $r$ be rotation by $\frac{360^\circ}{n}$, and $s$ be reflection across the $x$ axis.

Then clearly $r^n = 1$ and $s^2 = 1$. Also, you should convince yourself that $srs = r^{-1}$. It turns out that these rules completely describe $D_n$.

Comment: Isn't that a geometric rather than an algebraic definition?

Comment: The only way I can interpret "algebraic definition" is group presentation. Perhaps I should be more clear that the presentation is the point of the answer.